# Get fixed array values from unsafe struct

Tags: c#

I'm using an external C library that comes with a C# wrapper file containing a struct like (among many other things):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
unsafe public struct Data
{
    public fixed double Values[3];
};
```

I can get the values by adding an additional method to that struct:

```
public double[] CopyFixedDoubleArray()
{
    double[] result = new double[3];
    fixed (double* pDst = result)
    {
        fixed (double* pSrc = Values)
        {
            double* pd = pDst;
            double* ps = pSrc;
            for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
            {
                *pd = *ps;
                pd++; ps++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

But this is not what I want because I don't want to touch the wrapper file (to avoid having to keep the external file in our SCM repository). Whatever I try to do to get the values from outside that struct results in the following error:

> Fixed size buffers can only be accessed through locals or fields

What I've tried:

- `double a = data.Values[2];`
- `double a; unsafe { a = data.Values[2]; }`
- `double a; fixed (double* p = data.Values) { a = p[2]; }`
- `fixed (double a = data.Values[2]) { /* use a */ }`

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: Show us the code that would call `CopyFixedDoubleArray()` if `struct Data` contained the `CopyFixedDoubleArray()` method.

Comment: `double a = data.CopyFixedDoubleArray()[2];` for example

Comment: So, `Data data2 = data; double a; unsafe { a = data2.Values[2]; }` does not work?

Comment: Nope, results in that error

Comment: Hmmm, let's wait for the C# gurus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suddenly the word 'extension method' crossed my mind. And yes, I have it working:

```
public static double[] CopyFixedDoubleArray(this Data data)
{
    unsafe
    {
        return new[] { data.Values[0], data.Values[1], data.Values[2] };
    }
}
```

Comment: That's just bizarre. The extension method works, although the same method on the struct does not. I wonder why. Btw, saved my day, thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than patch your code up, have you considered shoving this over to the marshaller? That's its entire purpose: to assist with native interop while letting you write pure managed code.

You'd have to declare your `struct` like this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 8)]
public struct Data
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 3)]
    public double[] Values;
};
```

When this structure is filled by the marshaller (through either a direct function call through a pointer, or from mapping the `struct` on top of a byte buffer) it will allocate the proper array and copy its contents over. This makes your entire function obsolete, but if you really wanted to you could simply use `Array.Copy` (or the Linq equivalent).

Notice there's no more `unsafe` modifier. You can run this in a partially trusted environment with no issues!

Comment: Yes that's also how I would have written the wrapper. But this is not the case here as it comes from 3rd-party

Comment: Fair enough, just as long as you're aware the option exists!